# Address Sent in Text Message Opens Custom Mapping Application

Tags: java, android, geolocation

Correctly formatted addresses sent in text messages appear as links. When this link is clicked, how do I make it open my custom Android mapping app and automatically insert that address into my app's search box?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what it is you are trying to achieve and a reproducible example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). You need to register the types of links you want your app to respond to in the manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name="app.myActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos”-->
        <data
            android:host="gizmos"
            android:scheme="example" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->                
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can even simulate a deep link from the ADB:

> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos"
>
> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos"

You can then read the URI data and put it anywhere you like, as long as this is in the activity that responds to the deep link:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

**NOTE** 
WhatsApp is not a great place for deep links. I am still trying to figure out why.